# Cypher query on variable length path with specified end point

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

My graph model holds information on data lineage and how data moves from one column to another through column mappings in our ETL tool. A basic one hop pattern would look like this...

```
(source:Column)-[:SOURCE_OF_MAPPING]->(map:ColumnMapping)-[:TARGET_OF_MAPPING]->(target:Column)
```

so

- **source** might be a column called "STAGING_TABLE_1.FULL_NAME",
- **target** might be a column called "STAGING_TABLE_2.FULL_NAME" and
- **map** would be whatever was specified in the select query within the ETL tool's dataflow. Perhaps something like "UPPER(STAGING_TABLE_1.FULL_NAME || STAGING_TABLE_1.TITLE)"

What I need to be able to do is say if I look at a specific target column, lets say "DATA_MART_FACT_1.FULL_NAME", from which column does this data originate from?

The following is the cypher query I am trying to use but this only pulls back a single hop, i.e. the source and column mapping where the target is "DATA_MART_FACT_1.FULL_NAME".

```
MATCH (source:Column)-[:SOURCE_OF_MAPPING*]->(c:ColumnMapping)-[:TARGET_OF_MAPPING*]->(target:Column)
WHERE target.name = 'DATA_MART_FACT_1.FULL_NAME'
RETURN source, target, c
```

I have tried removing the relationship names, and just having an asterisk in the square brackets, but this just kills my neo4j installation (Currently sitting at 5GB memory and 50% CPU usage and hanging for around 10 minutes). There are constraints on all of the unique properties.

I know the data contains what I need because in the neo4j browser I can expand the nodes and follow the path through as I would expect to be able. Can anyone provide me with a cypher query that will allow me to do this? Perhaps my graph model needs a slight refactor in terms of relationship names and directions to allow this to work, which I'm perfectly happy to explore.

Here is some cypher to generate a basic example.

```
CREATE
(_0:`Column`  {`name`:"STAGING_TABLE_1.FULL_NAME"}),
(_1:`Column`  {`name`:"STAGING_TABLE_2.FULL_NAME"}),
(_2:`Column`  {`name`:"DATA_MART_FACT_1.FULL_NAME"}),
(_3:`ColumnMapping`  {`mappingText`:"UPPER(STAGING_TABLE_1.FULL_NAME)"}),
(_4:`ColumnMapping`  {`mappingText`:"LOWER(STAGING_TABLE_2.FULL_NAME)"}),
(_0)-[:`SOURCE_OF_MAPPING`]->(_3),
(_3)-[:`MAPS_TO`]->(_1),
(_1)-[:`SOURCE_OF_MAPPING`]->(_4),
(_4)-[:`MAPS_TO`]->(_2)
```

Then the query I used only return a single hop

```
MATCH (source:Column)-[:SOURCE_OF_MAPPING*..10]->(c:ColumnMapping)-[:MAPS_TO*..10]->(target:Column) WHERE target.name = 'DATA_MART_FACT_1.FULL_NAME' RETURN source, target, c
```

Then next query kind of returns what I'm after but is missing the relationship between the first 2 nodes.

```
MATCH (source:Column)-[:SOURCE_OF_MAPPING|MAPS_TO*..10]->(n)-[:MAPS_TO]->(target:Column) 
WHERE target.name = 'DATA_MART_FACT_1.FULL_NAME' 
AND (n:Column or n:ColumnMapping)
RETURN *;
```

The end result that I would like from this is as follows (note, aliases are just included here to illustrate the dataflow, and for my requirements the actual results don't need to be aliased)...

`(c1:Column)-[:SOURCE_OF_MAPPING]->(cm1:ColumnMapping)-[:MAPS_TO]->(c2:Column)-[:SOURCE_OF_MAPPING]->(cm2:ColumnMapping)-[:MAPS_TO]-(target:Column)`

and in tabular format
    source                    | mapping                          | target
    STAGING_TABLE_1.FULL_NAME | UPPER(STAGING_TABLE_1.FULL_NAME) | STAGING_TABLE_2.FULL_NAME
    STAGING_TABLE_2.FULL_NAME | LOWER(STAGING_TABLE_2.FULL_NAME) | DATA_MART_FACT_1.FULL_NAME

Oddly, when I created an [an interactive example](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ih48tz) (the site can be flaky and can sometimes take a few refreshes before it works) and although the table returns one row as per my local installation, the visual graph representation shows all of the expected nodes and relationships.

Any and all advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've refactored my column mapping to target column relationship direction to make the flow core natural as if it were the data flowing from source, to column mapping, to target. There was no change in behaviour though.

Comment: Are you able to share a sample of your example data? (Even better if you can share using http://console.neo4j.org/)  The query looks right (though, I'd recommend using `*..25` instead of `*`. Setting an upper length bound can help prevent runaway queries with highly connected graphs. Without seeing your data, it sounds like you have a data error where either the expanded relationship direction is pointing the wrong way, the type changes, or the actual pattern alternates between source and target mapping relationships.

Comment: Hi Tezra. I have knocked up an example and provided a link (and the cypher). Oddly on the console.neo4j.org link I provided which contains my graph example, I get different results from what I get when I run the query locally (with the same example graph as on the link provided)

Comment: Depending on your Neo4j version, You can safely do the relationship wildcard match if you use `RETURN DISTINCT` The DISTINCT will let the Cypher planner know it's ok to use a faster algorithm, because it doesn't need to know how many times a set is valid, just that it is. You're example data does not have any instances where `-[:SOURCE_OF_MAPPING*..10]->` can ever walk more than one edge, so the *..10 does nothing. You can use `-[:SOURCE_OF_MAPPING|MAPS_TO*..10]->` to match either relationship multiple times.

Comment: I'm a little confused what the expected results are. Can you also list the expected query results of the Neo4j console data is? The way I read your question, it sounds like the console example may already be right.

Comment: @Tezra I tried removing the ColumnMapping node from the query and changing the relationship to `-[:SOURCE_OF_MAPPING|MAPS_TO*..10]->` and although this did return 2 records, it was missing the ColumnMapping info (since it was omitted from the query) and it also had the final node `DATA_MART_FACT_1.FULL_NAME` as the target for both rows . I've added the expected output into the original question to show what I'm after. If this needs a change to data model then I'm more than happy to implement that. Apologies for the infrequent answers. I only get 1 day a week to look at this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example, the following is how to get the start to the end

```
MATCH (n)-[:SOURCE_OF_MAPPING|MAPS_TO*..4]->(target:Column) 
WHERE target.name = 'DATA_MART_FACT_1.FULL_NAME' 
AND (n:Column or n:ColumnMapping)
RETURN *;
```

I suspect for a real life example, where there may be many consecutive column mappings the results may have to be aggregated in some way in order to avoid killing performance with open ended variable length paths.

Answer (score 0):

You could try breaking your query using WITH, as:

```
MATCH (t:Column {name:'DATA_MART_FACT_1.FULL_NAME'})-[:TARGET_OF_MAPPING*]->(c)
WITH t, c 
MATCH (c)-[:SOURCE_OF_MAPPING*]->(s)
RETURN s,t,c
```

That can cut down on the Cartesian product situations.  I haven't tried in your case, but it's generally a good way to look at queries.  Also, trim the fat on criteria--if :TARGET_OF_MAPPING only connects to :ColumnMapping, then you may not need to specify and test for that.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but this still only returns a single column mapping with a single source and target. Your idea of splitting up the query does sound promising and would perhaps allow for a more flexible query. I'll do some more testing along those lines.